# armclang:error: couldn't allocate output register for constraint 'w'， but pass with GCC

Tags: arm, inline-assembly, armclang

I have an inline assembler code, and passed with arm-none-eabi-gcc,
compiled error with armclang.
Here is the sample code:

```
//wrong-reg.c

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>

#define __asm__ asm volatile
float __vabs(const float a) {
    //VABS{cond}.F32 Sd, Sm 
    float result;
    __asm volatile("vabs.f32 %0, %1" : "=w"(result) : "w"(a):);
    return result;
}

int __vcvta_s32(float a) {
    int result;
    __asm volatile("vcvta.s32.f32 %0, %1" : "=w"(result) : "w"(a):);
    return result;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    const uint8_t n4 = __vcvta_s32(__vabs(1 - 32.f / 100.0) * 100.0);

    printf("now n4 is %d", n4);
    return 0;
}
```

compiled with:

```
armclang --target=arm-arm-none-eabi -mcpu=cortex-m55 -O2 -g -c -mfpu=fp-armv8-fullfp16-sp-d16 wrong-regs.c -o wrong-regs.o
```

error:

```
wrong-regs.c:17:17: error: couldn't allocate output register for constraint 'w'
        __asm volatile("vcvta.s32.f32 %0, %1" : "=w"(result) : "w"(a):);
```

with gcc:

```
arm-none-eabi-gcc -mcpu=cortex-m55 -march=armv8.1-m.main+mve.fp+fp.dp -mfloat-abi=hard --specs=rdimon.specs -mfpu=auto -g -O2 wrong-regs.c -o wrong-regs-gcc
```

the result is okay.

```
armclang --version

Product: Arm Compiler for Embedded 6.17 Professional
Component: Arm Compiler for Embedded 6.17

arm-none-eabi-gcc --version

arm-none-eabi-gcc (GNU Arm Embedded Toolchain 10-2020-q4-major) 10.2.1 20201103 (release)
```

Comment: IMO gcc compiles using different FPU.

Comment: so while clang claims to be gcc/gas compatible, it isnt.   And gas has more than one floating point assembly language for the same instructions (completely different set of mnemonics for the same machine code) AND, using a compiler as an assembler is yet another assembly language.  AND inline assembly is compiler specific and not part of the C language.   So not really surprised here.  (so point being it does not matter if gcc works, you need to find the syntax for clang)

Comment: Looking at the [docs](https://developer.arm.com/documentation/101754/0618/armclang-Reference/armclang-Inline-Assembler/Inline-assembly-constraint-strings/Constraint-codes-for-AArch32-state?lang=en) (I'm hoping I've got that right), it says: *Operand must be a floating-point or vector type, or a 64-bit integer.*  While `a` is a float, `result` is just an int.  Have you tried using "w" for `a` and "=r" for `result`?

Comment: @DavidWohlferd, you are right, after change the type to float, it can generate the correct instruction. seems gcc understand more context, if still use int, it will generate  
      vcvta.s32.f32 s15, s0;         vmov    r0, s15 @ int

Comment: I suppose that technically clang is more correct by rejecting the mismatch between the variable and the constraint rather than 'fixing' it for you by assuming it knows what you meant.  Either way, at least now that you understand what's going on, you can modify to suit your needs.